# Let $G$ a group and $g,h∈G$. Prove that $|gh|=|hg|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $g,h∈G$. Prove that $|gh|=|hg|$.

A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hint.* $$g\color{red}{hghghghghghghghghg}h$$

Comment: hahahahahahahaha! Nice proof ;-)

Comment: I should have chosen my elements as $h,a∈G$ ;)

Comment: Slightly asthmatic as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: show that $hg$ and $gh$ are conjugated.

Comment: (Two elements $a$ and $b$ are conjugate if there exists $g\in G$ such that $gag^{-1}=b$.)

Answer (score 0):

If $|gh|=k\in N,k\ne 1$(for $k=1$ is trivial)  then,

$e=(gh)^k=g(hg)^{k-1}h$

$\Rightarrow (hg)^{-1}=g^{-1}h^{-1}=(hg)^{k-1}$(by multiplying with $g^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$ on the left and right of th above eqn.

$(hg)^k=e$(Multiplying with $hg$ on both sides of th above eqn.)

Similarly for the other case by reversing the roles for $h$ and $g$.